# Add attachment to Task List in SharePoint Online from Site Mailbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, attachments

I'm looking for a way to add an attachment to a specific Task within a list from a library or list.

We have SharePoint Online as part of our E3 subscription.

The ideal scenario is files are emailed to SharePoint and attach them directly to a pre-existing task without having to download the file locally, select the task, choose 'attach item' and browse to the required file.

Ideally I wanted to be able to drag from the list or library web app to the task list web app from within the page but I do not believe this is possible.

I then went to create a workflow to provide a list of open tasks and a list of unassigned delivery notes and assign them that way, but without infopath to create the initiation form I could see no way of using an attachment or create a filtered list.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to accomplish this or even if it is possible.